# Put font color in a certain line or word using C programming

Tags: c, windows-7, dev-c++, conio

I tried the system("COLOR 0a"); but it will change all the font color to that color. I also tried the textcolor(4) it gives me an error, the error message is textcolor is undeclared but I include the conio.h. What the problem?

NOTE: Im using windows 7 as an operating system

My codes

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
int main()
{
    textcolor(4);
    cprintf("dkfjdk");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Windows 7 and using dev c++ as a IDE

Comment: Don't add important details in comments. Instead, [edit] your question and put them there, where people you're asking for help can see them.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Windows function [`SetConsoleTextAttribute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686047(v=vs.85).aspx). A list of attributes is [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682088(v=vs.85).aspx#_win32_character_attributes).

The following will print "hello world" in bright red. Note that you'll want to reset the colour to the default (grey) if you want to print something else in grey afterwards.

```
fflush(stdout);
SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), FOREGROUND_RED | FOREGROUND_INTENSITY));
printf("hello world\n");
```

Note: The first call to `fflush(stdout)` is to ensure that any previously printed text appears in grey.

Note: make sure to `#include <windows.h>`

Comment: I got error it said expected ; before ) where is it? SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), FOREGROUND_RED | FOREGROUND_INTENSITY));

Comment: @WatchaGonnaDo Aha, the typo in this answer was *totally* intentional, I swear. If you know C then you should be able to find the mistake in that line yourself.

Answer (score 0):

try `textcolor(blue);`

```
code-reference.com/c/conio.h/textcolor
```